# Unable to create abstract Vertex Type on OrientDB 2.2.12 on partitioned graph

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

Trying to create an abstarct Vertex type on OrientDB 2.2.12 I Obtain the following exception.
The code worked on OrientDB 2.2.0

```
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSecurityException: Class 'MyVertexType' cannot be truncated because has record level security enabled (extends 'ORestricted')
    DB name="mydb"
    DB name="mydb"
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.binary.OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.throwSerializedException(OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.java:437)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.binary.OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.handleStatus(OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.java:388)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.binary.OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.beginResponse(OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.java:270)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.binary.OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.beginResponse(OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.java:162)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.beginResponse(OStorageRemote.java:2138)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote$27.execute(OStorageRemote.java:1160)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote$2.execute(OStorageRemote.java:196)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.baseNetworkOperation(OStorageRemote.java:235)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.networkOperationRetry(OStorageRemote.java:193)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.networkOperation(OStorageRemote.java:204)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.command(OStorageRemote.java:1136)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandRequestTextAbstract.execute(OCommandRequestTextAbstract.java:69)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OClassImpl.setAbstract(OClassImpl.java:1369)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OClassAbstractDelegate.setAbstract(OClassAbstractDelegate.java:63)
    at com.acme.Test.main(Test.java:68)
```

You can find the a complete project to reproduce this behaviour at
https://github.com/lucafrosini/test-orientdb-2-2-12

By debugging I found that the cause is:

```
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException:  Impossible to remove the last cluster of class 'Entity' drop the class instead
    DB name="mydb"
    DB name="mydb"
```

Comment: Have you tried following this procedure: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Partitioned-Graphs.html ?

Comment: I made exactly that in Java until
ALTER CLASS V SUPERCLASS ORestricted
then I create a type. 

Instead the procedure is related to instance creation.

Comment: I've reproduced it, can you open an issue on github? Thanks.

Comment: Sure. Thank you very much

Comment: I just created the bug on github. Here it is.
https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/6849